# Use class A which includes class B from class B

Tags: c++, qt

I have four files:

---

mainwindow.h

```
#pragma once // MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
#include "maincontent.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();
        void setStatusBarMessage(QString message);

    signals:

    public slots:
        void exit();

    private:
        void setMenuBar();
        MainContent* content;
};
```

---

maincontent.h

```
#pragma once // MAINCONTENT_H

#include "statistic.h"
#include "information.h"
#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>

class MainContent : public QWidget
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MainContent(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    signals:

    public slots:

    private:
        QHBoxLayout* layout;
        Statistic* statistic;
        Information* financFlow;
};
```

---

information.h

```
#pragma once // INFORMATION_H

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QWidget>
//#include "mainwindow.h" //error

class Information : public QWidget
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Information(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    signals:

    public slots:

    private:
        QPushButton* button;
};
```

---

statistic.h

```
#pragma once // STATISTIC_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QListView>

class Statistic : public QWidget
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit Statistic(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    signals:

    public slots:

    private:
        QListView* listView;
};
```

Now I will use the `MainWindow::setStatusBarMessage`method from the `Information` class.

But when I include the `MainWindow` in the Information class: `#include "mainwindow.h"`
I become the error: `MainContent does not name a type` in line 22 in mainwindow.h

First I don't know why the compiler can't find `MainContent` bacause in `MainWindow` I included the "maincontent.h", does the preprocessor only include "mainwindow.h" but not the "maincontent.h" in the "mainwindow.h"?

I see that with `#include "mainwindow.h"` a recursion arise but that shouldn't be a problem because of `#pragma once` or?

Next I tried to include the "mainwindow.h" in the information.cpp file but then I have the problem that I everytime give the `MainWindow` object by parameter and can't hold a `MainWindow` in my class

My main problem is that the `MainWindow` has a statusBar Object and I will set the statusBar message from everywhere. How can I do this, exist a Pattern or someting for that?

How can I solve this Problem or where I make a thinking mistake?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use forward declaration for your included classes. Since pointers itself do not need to know a fully declared class (pointer size is always the same) you can easily get around this:

In header File instead of include the class just declare it:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>
//#include "maincontent.h" // REmove these
class MainContent;
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();
        void setStatusBarMessage(QString message);

    signals:

    public slots:
        void exit();

    private:
        void setMenuBar();
        MainContent* content;
};
```

In cpp file now include the header again. Do this for all includes only having a pointer to given class.

As mentioned by @dempzorz removing the circular dependency is always prefered, but not always possible.

Comment: Thank you! Is it general better to use forward declaration when the header only contains pointer to these objects?

Comment: We prefer to forward declare given the advantages: 1) Compile time can be reduced since the include itself will trigger a seek on disk for the include file. 2) Changing a header file will not result in a rebuild if its forward declaration only in header file 3) Its easier to read in my opinion

Answer (score 2):

You have a circular dependency.  You can't have `information.h` include `mainwindow.h` and **also** have `mainwindow.h` include `information.h`.  You should design dependencies in a hierarchy, where items lower in the tree do not include items higher in the tree.

You should have a look at this link to maybe give you a better understanding of how to structure your objects:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency

Comment: Thank you, that despripes why it's doesn't work. I edit my question and add my main issue or what I finally want to do. Can you help my there to?